# Select particular data from linux command output executed from ssh as variable in php code

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I would like to select particular data from command output which is executed through ssh with php script. reuse selected particular data as variable.

Command line output as below

````
=> Processing triangulated mesh
=> Generating perimeters
=> Generating skirt
Done. Process took 0 minutes and 10.266 seconds
Meters required: 13537.8mm (95.7cm3) ```

Here from above output i would like to select '13537.8' to reuse in php script
Suggest me code how to select data and use as variable in php script

I tried to save output to text file and copy data using "grep" is now working.
grep -Po '(Meters required: \K[^ ]+)' /root/convertlog/89941a6fdd9ddd5f641faf46b05cd0b0f629.txt
````